# debian machine mounting filesystem read-only

Tags: linux, debian, mount, read-only, fstab

At work we have an old debian machine that I need to install security updates on, but the filesystem is mounted read-only. Unfortunately the guy who installed it has already retired and has not documented what he did on this machine.

output of `mount`:

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=63624,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=51512k,mode=755)
/dev/disk/by-label/rootfs0 on / type ext2 (ro,noatime,errors=continue)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/dev/sda4 on /mnt type ext2 (rw,noatime,errors=continue)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
tmpfs on /var/log type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
tmpfs on /var/tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
```

I took a look at /etc/fstab which looks kinda strange, since I can't see an entry for /:

```
LABEL=data      /mnt    ext2    defaults,noatime,rw     0       2
proc            /proc   proc    defaults                0       0
tmpfs           /tmp    tmpfs   nosuid,nodev            0       0
```

Where else could there be a settings, that mounts the filesystem read-only?

Comment: I remember I had this happen but don't recall the answer.  But I do know for sure I found it by exercising some Google Fu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/` is not initially mounted via `fstab` because to get to `/etc/fstab` you need to have `/` mounted. It is mounted via kernel `root=` option. The `ro` parameter is probably in your bootloader configuration (like `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`) as it should be.

Later during boot `/` is remounted according to `fstab`; the `rw` option should be there. In your case there's no proper entry so the `ro` option stands.

You may want to read more: *[How is `/etc/fstab` accessed before root is mounted?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107830/108618)*

---

#### Solution

Remount as read-write by hand:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

If you want to make a permanent change then create proper `/` entry in `/etc/fstab` with `rw` option.